# box2d physics goes wrong on iPad Retina (non 64) simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

When I run my cocos2d game on all iPhone, iPad or iPad Retina(64-bit) simulator everything is fine.  But when I run it on iPad Retina (non 64-bit) physics goes mad. Joints became floppy and bodies flying everywhere. Everything goes wrong only on this simulator. Why is that thing happen?

Comment: what about devices? That's the only thing that matters.

Comment: iPhone 4, 4s, 5 working great. Cannot test it on actual iPad 3 or 4, because i don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

Simulator can behave abruptly while testing a physics game. Sometimes it becomes slow and shows overlapping among bodies.

But It will behave properly on device. You should try on iOS device.

Moreover, You should consider using the following "draw" method to have closer look at body movements.

```
-(void) draw
{
    // IMPORTANT: This is only for debug purposes. It is recommend to disable it
    [super draw];
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    world->DrawDebugData();
    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```